# Where should I ask Docker networking related questions?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

On Stack Exchange, where would you ask a question related to networking or network configuration in [Docker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_%28software%29) / [Docker Compose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_%28software%29#Tools) (especially if you are still 'somewhere in the middle/lowest part' of the learning curve)?

As a non-expert in both Docker and networking concepts, I'm facing difficulties when it comes to selecting the most appropriate site, if any.

For example, [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [Super User](https://superuser.com/tour), [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/tour), [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour), etc.
Which would be more suited (and what are their respective pros/cons)?

Comment: Could you [edit] in your specific proposed question?

Comment: Most of those sites are [described here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on). Does that help?

Comment: Related: *[What is the best place to raise questions related to Docker and Kubernetes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347666/)*, *[Why is this Docker question off-topic?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179249/)*, *[Where should I ask about Docker/Django configuration?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308160/)*, *[Where is a good place to ask this question about DevOps?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283084/)*, and *[Are Docker questions off-topic?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193614/)*.